# working with codeigniter using bootsrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, database, datatable

I am new to **CodeIgniter** and I displayed table from DB using **Boostrap**, **jQuery** and **DataTable**.

However jQuery and DataTable don't work and showing error like this

[image]

here is my source code from View header where I liked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `the site_url();` in image src